Is there a way to manual set Akeneo PIM access token expiry time
Hi Is there a way to manual override  access token expiry in time of Akeneo API. I am using Bitnami AWS image. Have no idea where to look at
bitnami has put Akeneo support documents offline, nowhere to ask them. I can see there is a value in security.yml under packages to control refresh token.
